# If a scalar has a size, a vector has a size and direction, does a matrix have an additional property?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

This is more of a question of definitions, but I was just contempating how we say that a scalar value is a size, and nothing more. A vector value has a size (magnitude) as well as a direction.

If we're talking about things like the row space and column space of a matrix, we could say that one geometrical manifestation of matrices is the set of spaces you can make using these vectors as spans.

Are there any other intuitive ways of looking at what a matrix represents geometrically? Or is it more of an abstract concept that happens to *partly* manifest itself in ways that we can visualize?

Apologies if the question is too hand-wavy.

Comment: For starters, every matrix is a vector so it can be described also by size and direction if you want

Comment: "Are there any other intuitive ways of looking at what a matrix represents geometrically?" -- Matrices can be used to represent linear transformations. In particular, the determinant of a square matrix can be used to represent how it (the linear transform it corresponds to) scales the "content" of the space it's affecting. For instance, say $T : \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^2$ has $\det(T) = 3$. Then any shape on the $xy$ plane has its area tripled. For instance, the $1\times 1$ unit square will now have an area of $3$ (though not necessarily remain a square). (Similar ideas hold for volume, etc.)

Comment: There are an infinitie number of norms one can define on matrices. Same with vectors. So size, yes.  Dont really know how you define a direction on matrices.

Comment: @SquishyRhode You interpret a $p\times q$ matrix as a vector in a $pq$-dimensional space.

Answer (score 2):

A matrix $M$ can be thought of as having one direction for each of its rows, describing where $Mv$ ends up for choices of the column vector $v$ comprising a basis. You could also identity the directions $uM$ ends up in for row vectors $u$, one for each column of $M$. The matrix bundles all these together, just as a direction bundles numbers. But as @MaximilianJanisch noted, you can instead think of the matrix as a vector, in a space whose basis elements have two indices (which is easily changed to $1$). As @EeveeTrainer noted, some more information is present with square matrices, because such matrices of a given size are closed under multiplication viz. $\det MN=\det M\det N$.